# Send notification from laravel store function

Tags: php, laravel

I have notification system which will send my posts to telegram channel as soon as they created.

> This is source:
>   https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/telegram

My notification system works just fine and the only issue i have is that i cannot get the correct post link, I send notification once post has created from my `PostController` under store function.

I have simply this code after `$post->save();`

```
$post = \App\Post::first();
$post->notify(new \App\Notifications\PostPublished($post));
```

As you can see it always send post id `1` to my telegram channel i even tried `find(1)` and got same result.

**My question is now:  How to get the same post that created to be send to my channel?**

Comment: This article describes exactly what you're asking for https://codezen.io/sending-telegram-notifications-in-laravel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code: `$post = \App\Post::first();` get you first row in posts table

it means you always get first row in table

you dont need to use after `$post->save();`

just send notification without using `$post = \App\Post::first();` after save

for example:

```
$post->save();
$post->notify(new \App\Notifications\PostPublished($post));
```